# Eigen row of a M-N matrix multiply column of a N-M matrix in element wise

Tags: eigen, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix

```
A = a11  a12  a13 
    a21  a22  a23
```

and another matrix

```
B = b11  b12 
    b21  b22 
    b31  b32
```

How can I get the following vector using Eigen?

```
a11 * b11 + a12 * b21 + a13 * b31
a21 * b12 + a22 * b22 + a23 * b32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want coefficient-wise multiplication, so you have to use arrays ; because of the dimensions you will also need to transpose, and finally since you want a result of shape (Mx1) you will need a rowwise sum. So that gives you the following :

```
auto A = Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 3>::Random().eval();
auto B = Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 2>::Random().eval();

Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 1> C = (A.array()*B.transpose().array()).rowwise().sum();
```

Comment: Assertion failed: aLhs.rows() == aRhs.rows() && aLhs.cols() == aRhs.cols(), file

Comment: I'm sorry @arifle but this snippet does not yield the assertion you mention. I suspect the code you tried was somehow different because there was a small syntax error in my example and it should not even have compiled (it's fixed now). So please, edit your question with the code you are actually using if you want help

Comment: Sorry @trialNerror. The two matricies declared in my code are of Eigen::MatrixXd A, B. Maybe this is the problem? BTW, it is actually A and A.transpose in the code.

Comment: As I mentioned I won't be able to help you if you don't provide me the relevant section of your code. Eigen tells you that you have matrices with incompatible types, and this is not due to my code. Please update your question accordingly. Your matrices being of dynamic dimensions (MatrixX) is not the root cause